# word usage ' empower '

Tags: word-usage

> Is the expression 'culture **empowers** the language' correct?

Here I'd like to express the idea that language contains certain culture, the culture shapes a language and makes the language more attractive and meaningful.

I want to use this in my graduate application essay, I'm going to apply the Bilingual/ bi-cultural education in the States.

Comment: It's grammatically "correct", but *semantically* I don't think it works because language is an abstract concept, with no "autonomous mind", or "sense of purpose". I would say you can't "empower" language any more than you can give it confidence, or reassure it, for example. But I don't think this question is really about "use of English" at all - it's about the fact that the idea you're trying to express doesn't exactly make sense. I would say language *reflects* culture (and thus, culture *shapes* language).

Answer (score 2):

Your use of **empower** is to have the meaning of **effects**, **enables**, **enhances**.
It is **cleverly used** instead of the more generic

> **powers** a language

If you are speaking about a **specific language**

> In French, culture empowers **the** language

if you are speaking about how culture effects different languages

> culture empowers **a** language

if you are referring to how culture impacts language development in general

> **culture empowers language**.  For example

The latter could be used as a tag line for a course that teaches **cultural differences in various languages**

> In French the use of "**you**", meaning the person being spoken to, can have a polite/formal "**vous**"and an informal/familiar form "**tu**", such distinction does not exist in English.
>
> Eskimos have 28 different words for **snow**

In general, having many words meaning which have slightly different meanings shows what the culture behind a language considers important.

> In **Chinese**, different words are used to reference relatives are different for one's **mother's side** versus **one's father's side**, as well as whether the relation is **older** or **younger**. Family structure is very important in Chinese culture and the language reflects this.

Knowing these differences between and within languages can also be very **empowering** to the knowledgable.